# Export multiple .gpkg polygons as a shapefiles using a particular field name

Tags: qgis

I split polygons into separate polygons that where connected. when I ran the function vector/data management  tools/split vector layers. it created .gpkg files. i want to export from QGIS as shapefiles and name them from a field in the attribute table . is there a function in QGIS to do a bulk export of individual polygons and rename based on field ?

Answer (score 1):

I used the plugin Bulk vector exporter and used lupus re name